How to store structured data in a python package?
I'm currently developing a python package which among other things generates maps for a very low resolution driving game.
The maps are generated by combining predefined tiles. Those tiles have to be stored somehow. Each tile is a 9x9 array of sets containing zero to three strings. There are about 30 of those tiles.
Currently I store the tiles as constants in a python file and simply import them when I have to use them. I don't think it is affecting the performance (the file is only 89 KB big).
However, this dosn't feel very elegant. While the data is technically human readable, the file is to big to usefully look at (~3000 lines) or edit.
I could transfer the data to json files, but that would not make it any more readable and add an extra decode step when using it. I don't want to use pickle because changes to pickled files can't be usefully tracked by git.
The ideal solution would be both plain text (so that changes can usefully be tracked by git) and not complicated when publishing the package (I heard that a extra setup step is necessary when accessing non-python files in a package?).

How about one tile per file in a maps folder with and __init__.py to pull them together as a module?

@JonSG That is probably the best way to store the data directly within python files

Well there is a simple solution, DON'T USE PICKLE. There are python packages for JSON  the helps in storing and loading the data. The package 'json' will do it for you. Also JSON is plain text file, so it can be tracked using Git.
Example:
import json

data = {
    "tiles": [
        [
            [{0}, {1}, {2}],
            ...
        ],
        [
            [{3}, {4}, {5}],
            ...
        ]
    ]
}

# STORING

with open("tiles.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

# LOADING

with open("tiles.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

You also mentioned about the file being less elegant. With JSON that problem can be rectified. json.dump has a parameter 'indent' which will address your problem.
Alternatively you can use YAML, which is also readable and traceable by Git.

You can use a CSV file to store the data, which would store each tile like this (you can also align the commas to make it more readable):
["a", "a"], ["a"], [], ["a", "a", "a"], ["a"], [], ["a", "a"], ["a"], []
...
["a"], [], [], ["a", "a"], [], ["a"], [], ["a", "a", "a"], []

You can store each  in separate files (tile_0.csv, tile_1.csv, etc.) or all in one file (tiles.csv) and separate the tiles with empty lines for readability. Since you only have about 30 9x9 tiles, the runtime is negligible.
If this doesn't work, YAML or JSON files could work too, but I don't see much of a more readable solution since it is 30 9x9 sets of strings.
If they are in one file
import csv

tiles = []
current_tile = []

with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # Skip empty rows
        if not row or all(cell.strip() == "" for cell in row):
            # Save current tile and start new one
            if current_tile:
                tiles.append(current_tile)
                current_tile = []
            continue
        
        # Parse the row into lists of strings
        parsed_row = [eval(cell) for cell in row]
        current_tile.append(parsed_row)

# Add the last tile if not already added
if current_tile:
    tiles.append(current_tile)

If they are in separate files
import csv

num_tiles = 30
tiles = []
current_tile = []

for i in range(num_tiles):
    with open(f"tiles/tile_{i}.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        
        for row in reader:
            # Parse the row into lists of strings
            parsed_row = [eval(cell) for cell in row]
            current_tile.append(parsed_row)

        tiles.append(current_tile)
        current_tile = []


Edit: sorry, I misread your intro. you have strings that represent or map to images? I assumed the underlying data was numeric. I'm leaving my answer as is, even if it doesn't answer your exact question. you're better off probably just using a json format, considering your data is strings, where the array is jagged (unequal size).
Your data is numeric. I don't think the ideal solution here is to be human readable, but rather scalable.
It is Better to store this as an hdf5 file. Experiment with various compression algorithms to improve compression ratio and/or IO read times. The beauty of the hdf5 format is you can also store metadata with each of your "tiles." Furthermore, it is kinda like a file archive, where you have a single file path, comprised of multiple internal files (in this case your tiles).
If your data is images, you can achieve even better compression by casting to np.uint8. But again this depends on your data.
Here are some helper functions to get started:
import os
from timeit import timeit

import h5py
import hdf5plugin
import numpy as np


def write(
    path: str,
    array: np.ndarray,
    compression: h5py.filters.FilterRefBase,
    name: str = "pilot",
    mode: str = "a",
    metadata: dict | None = None
) -> None:
    with h5py.File(path, mode=mode) as file:
        dataset: h5py.Dataset = file.create_dataset(
            name,
            data=array,
            compression=compression,
        )
        if metadata is not None:
            dataset.attrs.update(metadata)


def read(path: str, key: str = "pilot") -> np.ndarray:
    with h5py.File(path, mode="r") as file:
        if key not in file:
            raise KeyError(f"Key not Found: {key}")
        ds: h5py.Dataset = file[key]

        return np.asarray(ds,dtype=ds.dtype)


def evaluate_hdf5_compressions(
    comps: list[tuple[str, h5py.filters.FilterRefBase]],
    path: str,
    array: np.ndarray,
    key: str = "pilot",
    iterations: int = 100
) -> dict[str, tuple[float, float]]:
    results: dict[str, tuple[float, float]] = {}
    for (name, c) in comps:
        write(path, array, c, key, "w")
        size: float = os.stat(path).st_size / 1000.0
        io_read_time: float = timeit(lambda: read(path, key), number=iterations)
        results[name] = (size, io_read_time)

    return results


Then evaluate different compressors available from hdf5plugins:
# create a list of available or relevant lossless compressors (this is not exhaustive)
compressors: list[tuple[str, h5py.filters.FilterRefBase]] = [
    *[
        (f"Blosc:{j}", hdf5plugin.Blosc(j, clevel=9))
        for j in ("blosclz", "lz4", "lz4hc", "zlib", "zstd", "snappy")
    ],
    *[
        (f"Blosc2:{k}", hdf5plugin.Blosc2(k, clevel=9))
        for k in ("blosclz", "lz4", "lz4hc", "zlib", "zstd")
    ],
    ("BZip2:9", hdf5plugin.BZip2(9)),
    ("LZ4:1MB", hdf5plugin.LZ4(1024 * 1024)),
    ("Zstd:22", hdf5plugin.Zstd(clevel=22))
]


# Short demo
a: np.ndarray = np.arange(1024 * 1024).reshape((1024, 1024)).astype(np.uint32)
path = "example.hdf5"

analysis: dict[str, tuple[float, float]] = evaluate_hdf5_compressions(compressors, path, a)

# then evaluate by what is important, storage size, or read times.

In your pyproject.toml, you'll need to include package data. Here is an example if you use setuptools:
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"path.to.data" = [ "*.hdf5" ]

